# solr-jetty 4.0.0 error BoolField$1$1 overrides final method setReader

Tags: solr, java, solrcloud, jetty-8

I've got 4 nodes SolrCloud cluster with separate zookeeper ensemble. I used https://launchpad.net/~blubolt/+archive/preciseplatform repo to get solr-jetty.
When I'm starting jetty8 I got this in my logfile:

```
    Nov 25, 2012 4:20:26 PM org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema readSchema
INFO: Schema name=example
Nov 25, 2012 4:20:26 PM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: null:java.lang.VerifyError: class org.apache.solr.schema.BoolField$1$1 overrides final method setReader.(Ljava/io/Reader;)V
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:415)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:377)
        at org.apache.solr.schema.BoolField.<clinit>(BoolField.java:66)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:432)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.newInstance(SolrResourceLoader.java:459)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.newInstance(SolrResourceLoader.java:455)
        at org.apache.solr.schema.FieldTypePluginLoader.create(FieldTypePluginLoader.java:81)
        at org.apache.solr.schema.FieldTypePluginLoader.create(FieldTypePluginLoader.java:43)
        at org.apache.solr.util.plugin.AbstractPluginLoader.load(AbstractPluginLoader.java:142)
        at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.readSchema(IndexSchema.java:369)
        at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.<init>(IndexSchema.java:113)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.getSchemaFromZk(CoreContainer.java:1438)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:837)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:539)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:312)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:106
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:114)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:755)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:258)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1221)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:699)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:454)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.WebAppDeployer.scan(WebAppDeployer.java:309)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.WebAppDeployer.doStart(WebAppDeployer.java:189)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:63)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:53)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:91)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:262)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1215)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1138)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:602)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:82)
```

At myhostname:8983/solr/# I see admin interface with "Loading ..." on every link.
Same thing with default or custom schema.xml
It seems like something breaking scheme parser.
Any ideas?

Comment: are you using the example settings comes with the solr distribution? it could help people here to help you if you could put some of your configs if you have changed any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question closed. Never use one config dir for a different solr versions. 
Removed /etc/solr/collection1/conf, removed zookeeper data, then reinstalled solr-common and solr-jetty with latest version. Everything is ok now.